# Cube SQL ORA-00936 missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

im trying using cube in my query but it didnt work
this is my query

```
select department_id, job_id , salary/12 as "monthly_salary"
from employees
where department_id
(select department_id from departments)
group by cube(department_id,job_id)
order by department_id,job_id;
```

by using 2 tables which is employees and departments
forgive me if im asking too much,im still new to this :)

Comment: provide some sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: What is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing

- `IN` keyword (for list of departments)
- `SUM` function for salaries

  - I included `ROUND` so that it looks prettier

So:

```
  SELECT department_id, 
         job_id, 
         ROUND (SUM (salary) / 12) monthly_salary
    FROM employees
   WHERE department_id IN (SELECT department_id FROM departments)
GROUP BY CUBE (department_id, job_id)
ORDER BY department_id, job_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are asking, but here is an example of a cube to get totals by deptno, job and the combination of the two

```
SQL> select deptno,job,sum(sal) from scott.emp
  2  group by CUBE(deptno,job)
  3  order by deptno,job;

    DEPTNO JOB         SUM(SAL)
---------- --------- ----------
        10 CLERK           1300
        10 MANAGER         2450
        10 PRESIDENT       5000
        10                 8750
        20 ANALYST         6000
        20 CLERK           1900
        20 MANAGER         2975
        20                10875
        30 CLERK            950
        30 MANAGER         2850
        30 SALESMAN        5600
        30                 9400
           ANALYST         6000
           CLERK           4150
           MANAGER         8275
           PRESIDENT       5000
           SALESMAN        5600
                          29025
```